# Plantuml Stereotype style not being applied

Tags: plantuml

According to https://plantuml-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formatting/all-skin-params.html and the naming of the parameter, I assumed that `ClassStereotypeFontColor` will change the color of the `C` for class stereotypes in Plantuml. Unfortunately, this doesnt seem to work and I've not found other parameters which could do what I want (changing the color).

Chaning the border color or Backgroundcolor is easy by the way. But unfortunately, there is no `StereotypeCFontColor`

```
@startuml

skinparam StereotypeCBorderColor black
skinparam StereotypeCBackgroundColor green
skinparam ClassStereotypeFontColor red

class test {

}

@enduml
```

[image]

It seems that the Stereotype Character Color cant be changed. Am I on the wrong track or is this a bug? I'm using `plantuml.1.2020.19`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying all parameters and selectively changing color values, I've found out that the `CircledCharacterFontColor` parameter actually  changes the Stereotype font color. I still don't know what `ClassStereotypeFontColor` is doing, but this naming seems to be misleading.

Comment: `ClassStereotypeFontColor ` changes the font color of the class' name